# CakePHP 3 find() with beforeFind() callback SQL issue

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I'm having a problem with data integrity when using find() in my controller in conjunction with beforeFind() in a behavior callback.  The WHERE Submissions.site_id is not being added in the WHERE clause like it should be.  I get different result sets depending on where the WHERE clause is set.

in my SubmissionsController:

```
public function index()
{

    $query = $this->Submissions->find('all')
                ->where(['user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')])
                ->contain(['Users', 'Categories']);

    $this->set('submissions', $this->paginate($query));

}
```

In my beforeFind() Model callback (attached as a 'TenantBehavior' to

```
$query->where([$this->_table->alias().'.'.'site_id' => 3]);
```

The problem is that with the above, the SQL generated puts the "WHERE" clause as an AND on the JOIN condition like so, and NOT on the actual WHERE:

```
...
FROM 
submissions Submissions 
INNER JOIN users Users ON (
Users.id = (Submissions.user_id) 
AND Users.site_id = 3
) 
INNER JOIN categories Categories ON (
Categories.id = (Submissions.category_id) 
AND Categories.site_id = 3
) 
WHERE 
user_id = 315
```

If I remove the beforeFind() ->where and instead place it on the controller ->where I get the expected SQL and result set like so:

```
...
FROM 
submissions Submissions 
INNER JOIN users Users ON (
Users.id = (Submissions.user_id) 
AND Users.site_id = 3
) 
INNER JOIN categories Categories ON (
Categories.id = (Submissions.category_id) 
AND Categories.site_id = 3
) 
WHERE 
(
user_id = 315 
AND Submissions.site_id = 3
)
```

Thoughts? Suggestions?

EDIT
As @ndm's suggestion, I began to update and provide much more context.  In doing so I discovered (like an idiot) that I was missing the `$this->addBehavior('Tenant');` on my 'SubmissionsTable' model.  Adding this of course solved the issue.

Comment: Where exactly (in which class) is the before find callback located? Looks like it's in a behavior? If that's the case, then where and how is it being loaded? And what does the rest of the code in the callback look like? Please always include enough code and information for people to be able to reproduce the issue! Also please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly!

Comment: Wow. Thanks.  I began to update with a bit more info (I'm new here) and as you mentioned as I began to show that indeed the beforFind() code was being added in a behavior to the models is when I discovered I had failed to actually add the '$this->addBehavior('Tenant')' line to my SubmissionsTable.  Your asking for more info helped me realize my rookie mistake.  Big thanks, and lesson learned!

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->Submissions->find('all', [
            'conditions' => [
                 'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
             ],
             'contain' => [
                  'Users',
                  'Categories',
             ]
         ]);
```

Passing conditions as inline array will solve your issue and append beforeFind() where conditions properly.

Comment: How will that solve the issue when it will effectively create the same query as the fluid interface built one? Please always add at least a short explanation when posting code examples!

Comment: @diomedes, I tried that but am still seeing the same problem?